# HTML flash messages

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, mvc

Flash messages are generally composed in the controller. Sometimes we need those flash messages to have links in them (like an <kbd>undo</kbd> button).

How would you compose such a message?

The only sane way I have found to create such messages is by a presenter that includes much of ActionView in it (in order to gain access to most of the view helpers).

Right now the code in the controller looks like this:

```
def publish
  @post.publish!
  flash[:notice] = "Post <a href=\"/posts/#{@post.id}\">#{@post.title}</a> " +
    "was published successfully"

  redirect_to @post
end
```

and in the view I do a `<%= raw flash[:notice] %>` to display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have several options. One way to clean this up a bit would be to use Rails' [I18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) module, e.g.:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  post_successful_html: Post <a href="%{url}">%{title}</a> was
                        published successfully.

# the `_html` suffix marks the string as HTML-safe automatically
```

Then in your controller:

```rb
flash[:notice] = t :post_successful_html, :url   => post_path( @post ),
                                          :title => @post.title
```

And the view:

```html
<%= flash[:notice] %>
```

(You could also do this the other way around and just put "`:post_successful_html`" in `flash` and then call `t flash[:notice], :url => ...` in the view but that feels messier to me.) Using I18n for just one thing seems a little like overkill but it is nice and clean (and if you've ever considered localizing your your app it's never too early to start).

---

An alternative is to break what you need out into a partial, e.g. `_post_successful_flash.html.erb`:

```html
Post <%= link_to post.title, post %> was published successfully.
```

And then in your controller:

```rb
flash[:notice] = render_to_string :partial => 'post_successful_flash',
                                  :object  => @post, :as => :post
```

---

Finally, you could do it in a helper instead:

```rb
module PostsHelper
  def render_post_successful post
    "Post #{link_to post.title, post} was published successfully."
  end
end
```

Then in the controller:

```rb
flash[:notice] = :post_successful
```

And the view:

```html
<%= render_post_successful @post if flash[:notice] == :post_successful %>
```

---

Which one you should use is sort of a toss-up to me. I'm fond of the I18n approach but partly because I prefer to keep messages like this in locales anyway. Use whatever makes the most sense to you.

Comment: I think I'll use the `render_to_string` approach and might give a try to the i18n approach on a new project that's still young and fit for experimentation. Thanks :-)

Comment: Excellent idea to use render_to_string to do this!